# Regex with capturing parentheses and non-greedy matching constraints

Tags: python, regex

I just spent an hour trying to figure out the magic syntax to solve the following problem in Python with the 're' package. I have hacked around it for the moment, but would like to set out the challenge:

The following strings represent our test:

```
*Structure song &lt;!-- See Project:Project_Songs --&gt;
*Structure song |
*Structure song title |
```

The objective is to extract 'song', 'song', and 'song title' from these with a single regex.

My attempt:

```
r'\*Structure ([^\|]*)(?:&lt;)?'
```

I won't bore you with the various combinations I tried so far. My workaround adds the ampersand '&' to the exclusion set in the capturing parentheses. However, I'd rather not assume that the extracted string cannot include '&'.

Comment: Rather, what do you consider a trailing boundary for your matches?

Comment: what is the striking difference between 'title' pattern and some other thing you want to omit?

Comment: Rather than write complicated regexes, why not simply [`unescape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) it?

Comment: One way is to use negative lookahead. `re.compile(r'\*Structure ((?:[^\|](?!&lt;))+)')` although this will add a space in the `&lt;` case. Seems *marginally* faster than Dmitry's regex.

Comment: I am looking to extract the strings mentioned in the post: 'song' and 'song title'. I could certainly unescape the string, but I am working with a multi-TB file and doing additional scans of a string seems like it would be worse than a pure regex solution.

Comment: Have a look at my answer, it matches your songs well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a similar pattern as Dmitriy's, but a more linear one:

```
\*Structure\s(.*?)(?=\s(?:&lt;|\|))
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cF0fE7/2).

**Explanation**:

- `\*Structure` - a literal substring `*Structure`
- `\s` - a whitespace (replace with `[ \t]` to only match a normal space or tab, or with a mere space if you only need to match a space)
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 capturing 0+ chars other than a newline, as few as possible up to the first ...
- `(?=\s(?:&lt;|\|))` - (a positive lookahead requiring)

  - `\s` - a whitespace followed with either...

    - `&lt;` - a substring `&lt;`
    - `|` - or...
    - `\|`  - a literal pipe symbol.

A faster synonymic alternative (as it is based on the unroll-the-loop principle) regex will look like

```
\*Structure\s(\S*(?:\s(?!&lt;|\|)\S*)*)
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/cF0fE7/3)

It is the same regex but written in the most linear way.

Comment: 180 steps (Regex 1) vs. 98 steps (Regex 2). I would use Regex 2 in production.

Comment: Yes, this does what I'm looking for. I only updated to allow for variable numbers of spaces, since they are not fixed.

Comment: Well, if there is always at least 1 space, you just need to add a `+` quantifier: `\*Structure\s+(.*?)(?=\s+(?:&lt;|\|))` or `\*Structure\s+(\S+(?:\s+(?!&lt;|\|)\S+)*)`. Also, just in case you have a multiline input, you need to use a regular space  rather than `\s`.

Comment: @boardrider: It [does not work](https://regex101.com/r/lT9dM8/1) if the song has a `&` symbol.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using non-greedy "anything" followed by "&lt;" or pipe char represented as lookahead:

```
\*Structure (.*?(?= &lt;)|.*?(?= \|))
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/rT3oV5/2

Comment: Thanks for this, but it still breaks in the case that you have "| &lt;" following the desired string.